# stackpanel triggers and storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, storyboard, expander

When setting my stackpanel triggers for my expander content I begin a story board animation but how can I use the story board animation the same way in reverse?

```
<BeginStoryboard>
<Storyboard>
<DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.45" Storyboard.TargetName="content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

This will slowly slide out the expander contents but it snaps back like an original expander? I want to set it so it will also slowly come back in aswell as out?

For instance if I add/use on the DoubleAnimation:

```
AutoReverse="True"
```

When I click the expander it will open then close rather than open on click close on click? So not to sure how I can achieve my goal.

EDIT:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Expanded" SourceName="expander1">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.45" Storyboard.TargetName="content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" Name="expander1" OpacityMask="#6C806969" Background="#FF807171">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="  FORUMS" Foreground="#FFFCB798" FontSize="41" FontStretch="UltraExpanded">                      
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header> 
                <Grid x:Name="content" Background="#FF807171" Width="378">
                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="1"/>
                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `Storyboards`.

One does the **slide out** the other does the **slide in**.

Inside your `Expander` control you will need a `ToggleButton`. When this `ToggleButton` is `Checked`, fire the **slide out** animation, when it is `Unchecked`, fire the **slide in** animation.

**UPDATE**

I personally prefere to do this types of animations inside the style of the control, so you don't need to duplicate the code and they can be easily shared.

What I have done here is, I created a new `Expander` style based on its default style.

Inside the style, I set its `ExpandSite` to be always `Visible` and removed the code that made `ExpandSite` `Visible` when `IsExpanded` is set to `True`. Also I created two storyboards that handle the **slide out** and **slide in** animations.

In the **slide out** animation (i.e. `ExpandAnimation`), I set the `Visibility` of `ExpandSite` to `Visible` at the start and then animate its `ScaleX`; while in the **slide in** animation (i.e. `CollapseAnimation`), I animate its `ScaleX` first and set the `Visibility` to be `Collapsed` at the very end.

I have attached the full code for your reference.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="animationtest.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <TransformCollection>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                                </TransformCollection>
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <TransformCollection>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                                </TransformCollection>
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <TransformCollection>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                </TransformCollection>
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandAnimation">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="CollapseAnimation">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0"/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard
                            x:Name="ExpandAnimation_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ExpandAnimation}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard
                            x:Name="CollapseAnimation_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource CollapseAnimation}"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Expander Header="Expander" ExpandDirection="Right" Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle1}" IsExpanded="True">
            <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="  TEST" Foreground="#FFFCB798" FontSize="41" FontStretch="UltraExpanded">                       
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform> 
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/> 
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform> 
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <StackPanel OpacityMask="#6C806969" Background="#FF807171">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Margin="12" Width="240"/>
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Margin="12" Width="240"/>
                <Button Content="Button" Width="80" Margin="12"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But that doesnt explain how the animation is written, even if I have that if I use autoreverse the same will happen again.

Comment: Why would you use AutoReverse anyway? AutoReverse means the animation will run and reverse back to where it was. This is not what you need here.

Comment: It was all I could find under doubleanimation that might have did the trick is there another way?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want to click an expander button (say arrow-like) to expand your expander with a nice slide-out animation and click it again to collapse your expander with a slide-in animation, correct?

Comment: Yes I will post the code I have for it, as there are many examples but I found this one to be the simplest way.

Comment: Ok updated my question, pretty small bit of code that does alot for me just wished I had it in reverse.

Comment: Then you need two storyboards rather than one... You can't use one storyboard to do both animations.

Comment: I just cant see how tho, x:Name and SourceName can only be set once (for the toggle button idea)? And I still have no idea how the animation can slowly come in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10106/discussion-between-xin-and-kirsty-white)

Comment: Thats like way to much? I only get one error and thats the easingdoublekeyframe not found? I am actually shocked....

Comment: Yes, styles are normally pretty long... Normally you would use Expression Blend to mock round with them, without actually writing the code. Hmm... do you have a reference to system.windows.interactivity.dll?